# Autoreceptor control of phasic and postsynaptic control of tonic signalling

Tags: receptor, autoreceptor

I have read the following paragraph : "Whereas tonic DA signaling is affected by postsynaptic stimulation/blockade, phasic (transient) release of DA during dopaminergic cell bursting is modulated by presynaptic drug action (Grace, 1991)" in a paper by Frank & O'Reilly, 2006. Whereas I do find evidence that phasic release of DA is negativeley modulated by presynaptic drug action, I don`t understand why postsynaptic would mainly influence tonic DA signalling (and not phasic?). Can anyone help me out here or point me towards relevant literature?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some surrounding context? What is the book/paper about, what drugs are we talking about, etc.